# How to disable button when translation in one of the language selected is not available

Tags: angular, translation, angular-translate, ngx-translate

I'm trying to add a description to a form field on a page using angular Tooltip

I am checking if the translation is available for a particular label key in my ts file and if yes the button is enabled and it shows the description on hover

ts file

```
checkInfoExisting() {
this.isexisting = false
this.translate
  .get(this.selectedField.label)
  .subscribe(res => {
    if (res !== this.selectedField.label) {
      this.isexisting = true
    }
    this.information = this.selectedField.label
  })
 }
```

html file

```
<button [matTooltip]="information|translate" [disabled]="!isexisting" >
        <mat-icon>help_outline</mat-icon>
      </button>
```

I have two languages. I have defined the description in only one language and I want the button to be disabled when the translation in another language is not available